# Download and Save a ContentVersion document with Powershell

Tags: contentversion

I am looking for example of how to download a zip file in Powershell from a ContentVersion object.

I first download using a reference to the ContenVersion object using :

```
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $dwlurl -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer " + $access_token}
```

which works

then I try to make the conversion FromBase64String as:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($data)))
```

However, it throws this error:

```
Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it 
contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding 
characters. "
```

Has anyone done this with Powershell and Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the file you are downloading is composed entirely of UTF-8 characters?  For example, if it was a PDF or JPEG inside the zip - it won't be UTF-8

Comment: I don't know if it is UTF-8, i have tried it multiple ways. the documentation only states it is stored as:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

VersionData 
Type base64
Properties Create, Nillable, Update